# Can't invoke single query GET in WebApi OData

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have web api with OData controller. Models is

```
public class UserDto
{
   public int UserDtoId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

in controller I have two method

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<UserDto> Get();

[EnableQuery]
public SingleResult<UserDto> GetUser([FromODataUri] int key);
```

OData config is:

```
      ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
   builder.EntitySet<UserDto>("Users").EntityType.HasKey(e=>e.UserDtoId).Name = "User";
  config.MapODataServiceRoute(
    routeName: "ODataRoute",
    routePrefix: "odata",
    model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

when I try invoke odata/Users(123), the odata try to invoke first get not a get with a key and return me all record from table. When I comment out first get method there is none GET method for this URI access at all. Where I make a mistake?

I try to make [ODataRoute] its doesnt change nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, your two functions are `Get()` and `GetUser(int key)`
They should both be '`Get`'

Also not sure if it matters, but for the `Get(int)` one, if it still doesnt work, try changing `SingleResult<UserDto>` to just `UserDto`